# Compute the number of universal-arguments before digit argument

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, calling-convention

How can I find the number of `universal-arguments` used to invoke a command prior to a `numeric-argument`.

For example, how could I differentiate between `arg1` and `arg2` in the following (wrong) function?

```
(defun my-func (&optional arg1 arg2)
  (interactive "P\nP")
  (message "arg1: %S, arg2: %S, value: %S"
           arg1 arg2 (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)))
```

Use case, transparently passing the numeric prefix value to an advised command depending on the number of prior `universal-arguments`, eg. `dired` rename following `2` files in current dired buffer with <kbd>C-u 2</kbd> or to other dired buffer with <kbd>C-u C-u 2</kbd>.

Something along the lines of the following advice, but that actually passes the `2` properly to `dired-do-rename` instead of either `1` or `4`.

```
(define-advice dired-do-rename (:around (fun &rest args) "defer-dwim")
  (let ((dired-dwim-target (equal '(4) current-prefix-arg)))
    (apply fun (list (max 1 (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))))))
```

I see there is a `prefix-command-preserve-state-hook`, but it seems like significant additional effort to make that work.

Comment: I guess a workaround would be to use negative/positive arguments, but although simple, it would be annoying

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question is quite unclear to me - so this might not answer it.

You say "How can I find the number of universal-arguments used to invoke a command prior to a numeric-argument."  I'll answer that.

It doesn't matter how many times you write `"P"` in an `interactive` string spec. The value is the same each time, and multiple such occurrences do NOT correspond to multiple uses of `C-u`.

So `(interactive "P\nP\nP")` just produces three arguments that all have the same value - the value that comes from a single use of a prefix argument key sequence, whether that sequence is `C-u`, `C-9`, `M--3`, `C-u 360`, or `C-u C-u C-u`.

If you want your function to distinguish, say, `C-u`, `C-u C-u`, and `C-u C-u C-u` then it needs to test the raw prefix argument (what `"P"` specifies for `interactive`).

- `C-u` corresponds to the raw prefix arg `(4)`, that is, a list with just the number 4.
- `C-u C-u` corresponds to the raw prefix arg `(16)`.
- `C-u C-u C-u` corresponds to the raw prefix arg `(64)`.

`(prefix-numeric-value '(4))` returns 4; `(prefix-numeric-value '(16))` returns 16; and `(prefix-numeric-value '(64))` returns 64.

See the Elisp manual, node [Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).

You can practice with something like this command, to see what the resulting raw and numeric prefix arguments are when you type different prefix-arg key sequences:

```
(defun foo (arg narg)
  (interactive "P\np")
  (message "ARG: %S, NARG: %S" arg narg))
```

---

The rest of your question is completely unclear to me.  I don't understand what you're trying to do with "`dired-do-rename`.  If I'm right, please consider posting two separate questions: one asking how to distinguish `C-u` from `C-u C-u` and the other asking something (what?) about `dired-do-rename`.

Comment: Thanks, buit I know all this. The question was how to distinguish that the resulting value "3" say, coming from either "C-u 3" or "C-u C-u 3" and execute different actions,passing the numeric value (3) depending on the number of "C-u"'s.  Basically, exactly like the advice above would do.

Comment: `C-u 3` and `C-u C-u 3` are the *same* - they have the same effect; return the same value as raw prefix arg. There is never any reason for a user to use `C-u C-u 3`. I recommend reading the doc about this, as noted.

Comment: I have read the docs, that's why I asked. And they aren't the same, they are different sequences of keys that are made to appear the same as a final result because that's how `universal-preserve-state-hook` decides to do it in the normal case

Comment: I don't have the latest Emacs 27 snapshot, but there is no `universal-preserve-state-hook` in any Emacs release, at least, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: Oh my bad, it's called `prefix-command-preserve-state` in `simple.el` and it runs a `prefix-command-preserve-state`.  I'm on a new build, maybe its new, not sure.

Comment: So it sounds like (but still unclear) you want to change `dired-do-rename` and the normal handling of prefix-arg keys so that `dired-do-rename` can obtain some special value from `C-u C-u 3`, different from what `C-u 3` returns. Is that it? In that case I suggest you rewrite your question to (1) make clear the abnormal prefix-arg behavior you're looking for and (2) remove `dired-do-rename` from it. If that's your question then it is really about the mapping between keys used to produce a raw prefix arg and the prefix arg they produce.

Comment: (FWIW, I don't recommend changing the behavior of prefix argument-producing key sequences. It's possible to do that, but IMHO not advisable.)

Comment: I think the title and "How can I find the number of universal-arguments used to invoke a command prior to a numeric-argument." are pretty clear.  The `dired-do-rename` is just an example use case, the same advice would affect any `dired` command relying on `dired-dwim-tartget` for example, but it's not about dired.